# POST Caspio API

Tags: api, rest, post

I'm trying to post to Caspio's API - I've been able to perform POST & GET requests fine to get my token and retrieve data in XML from Caspio although having problems using the POST method to get data back into Caspio. In the example below I've encoded my body as `{"First_Name":"John"}`.

Currently I'm getting **415 Unsupported Media Type** - The server cannot service the request because the media type is unsupported.

```
var requestPost = new XMLHttpRequest();


 function PostWebAPI() {
       requestPost.open("POST", "https://c2ezh542.caspio.com/rest/v1/tables/Patient/rows", true);
       requestPost.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + token_);
       requestPost.send("%7B%22First_Name%22%3A%22John%22%7D");
```

The [table operations](http://howto.caspio.com/integration/web-services-api/rest-api/operations/table-operations/) specify the following:

POST Table Rows

```
/tables/<name>/rows
```

- Method: POST
- Description: Inserts a row into the table
- Parameters:
  URL, Body, required – {“field1″:”value1″,”field2″:”value2”}
- Result:
  201 Created (if successful) + Location Header contains URL to
  inserted row

Answer (score 0):

Use Following

```
var params= {“field1″:”value1″,”field2″:”value2”};
request.setRequestHeader("Accept", "application/json");
request.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json;charset=UTF-8");
request.send(JSON.stringify(params));

request.onreadystatechange = function () {`enter code here`
if (request.readyState == 4 && request.status== 201) {
     var obj = JSON.parse(response);
         }
}
```

}